# Cypress run fail show gpu_memory_buffer_support_x11.cc(44)] dri3 extension not supported

Tags: ubuntu, github, cypress, github-actions

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ri5YM.png)i run cypress on github actions, but after open cypress, will show
Opening Cypress...
[2687:1227/141010.802368:ERROR:gpu_memory_buffer_support_x11.cc(44)] dri3 extension not supported.

and  can not run all case, because  CypressError: `cy.visit()` failed trying to load:
and i check video, found it have no send ip to brower, how i can fix it?

my yml like this:

```
integration_testing_portal_edge:
    name: Testing EDGE Portal
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    needs: [deploy_edge_service]
    steps:
      - name: Checkout 
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Install node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
            node:version: '16'
            
      - name: Install dependencies
        working-directory: ./integration_test/NetProbe_E2E/cypress
        run: |
            npm ci 
            npm i -D cypress
            npm i -D @cypress/grep
            npm install -D @cypress/xpath
            npm i -D cypress-wait-until
            npm i --save-dev cypress-mochawesome-reporter
            
        
      
      - name: Cypress run
        working-directory: ./integration_test/NetProbe_E2E/cypress
        run: npx cypress run --env grepTags="@trap @probe"
```

actions result show:

```
  Running:  Configuration/TC6_1_10.cy.js                                                   (1 of 27)


  TC6_1_10 忘記密碼測試
    1) "before all" hook: Login,新增一個測試帳號, 權限為admin for "不輸入任何資訊點選取消以及確認"
    2) "after all" hook: 刪除測試帳號 for "不輸入任何資訊點選取消以及確認"


  0 passing (31s)
  2 failing

  1) TC6_1_10 忘記密碼測試
       "before all" hook: Login,新增一個測試帳號, 權限為admin for "不輸入任何資訊點選取消以及確認":
     CypressError: `cy.visit()` failed trying to load:

https://192.168.11.96:9999/Edge

We attempted to make an http request to this URL but the request failed without a response.

We received this error at the network level:

  > Error: ETIMEDOUT

Common situations why this would fail:
  - you don't have internet access
  - you forgot to run / boot your web server
  - your web server isn't accessible
  - you have weird network configuration settings on your computer
```

Answer (score 2):

[Cypress issue 25357](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/25357) discusses this problem and suggests the workaround for Cypress versions < `13.2.0`.

The problem is resolved in Cypress `13.2.0` and later.

To prevent the gpu error in Cypress `13.1.0` and earlier, add

```yaml
env:
  ELECTRON_EXTRA_LAUNCH_ARGS: '--disable-gpu'
```

to the GitHub workflow and use a browser other than the default Electron browser.

This only solves the error message

> [2687:1227/141010.802368:ERROR:gpu_memory_buffer_support_x11.cc(44)]
> dri3 extension not supported.

It does not solve the issue with `cy.visit()` which is a separate problem caused by the application under test being unavailable.